# No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I am trying to build a project with

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

But it throws an exception at the step **startScripts**

```
:common:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:common:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:common:classes UP-TO-DATE
:common:jar UP-TO-DATE
:common:findMainClass
:common:startScripts FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':common:startScripts'.
> No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
```

But I really do not need a main Class for this module. How should I settle this?

Comment: Which dependencies do you have on your spring-boot application? Is there a `spring-boot-starter` dependency?

Comment: no, I only have testCompile("junit:junit") in the dependency actually.

Answer (score 2):

There's an open ticket about this issue on Spring-Boot's GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2679. There are couple things you can do according to discussion:

- Remove `spring-boot` plugin from `buildscript` section. This will remove special Gradle tasks from build flow.
- Assign `mainClassName` to some random string. It's not pretty but as far as this is not runnable app you probably don't care about main class.
- There are some more bulky ways to solve this listed by the link if you want to try them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `main` method which calls `SpringApplication.run(...)`. Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
}
```

In the [*Gettings started*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-main-method) guide is a paragraph about the `main` method:

> The final part of our application is the main method. This is just a
>   standard method that follows the Java convention for an application
>   entry point. Our main method delegates to Spring Boot’s
>   SpringApplication class by calling run. SpringApplication will
>   bootstrap our application, starting Spring which will in turn start
>   the auto-configured Tomcat web server. We need to pass Example.class
>   as an argument to the run method to tell SpringApplication which is
>   the primary Spring component. The args array is also passed through to
>   expose any command-line arguments.

I recommend to create a `Application` class where it all starts:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But, perhaps you should start with the [*Quick start*](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) guide at first.

Comment: How about a library module, which is not necessary to have a main class, right?

Comment: If it's a library than you don't need the `spring-boot` plugin. What should the library do?

Comment: A `spring-boot` application is a self-contained application. If you have a library than it is not a `spring-boot` application.

Comment: Without spring-boot plugin, the way of config gradle will be different, for example, I cannot use testCompile("junit:junit") to add a dependency. I also cannot use those features provided by the plugin.

Comment: Of course you can have this dependency. You just need a simple `build.gradle` with 
`apply plugin: 'java' repositories { mavenCentral() } dependencies { testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' }`.

Comment: OK. If that is the case, I guess I should only apply the spring-boot plugin for the spring-boot modules, and have different config for non spring-boot modules. A little bit troublesome, but if have no choice, then I will do it.

Comment: I see. The thing is testCompile("junit:junit") may be using junit 4.11 rather than 4.12. So I need to tidy up the versions manually.

Comment: Ok, you have a `spring-boot` project but also some other projects like `common`? Than you need to setup a multi-project gradle configuration. I found a [blog post](https://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/how-to-configure-spring-boot-with-jpa-and-multiple-projects/) about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following at the end of my `build.gradle` to define the name of the main class.

I also use `gradlew bootjar` instead of `gradlew build`.

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.spring.xx.app.App'
}
```