# ShadowJar: No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'

Tags: gradle, uberjar, gradle-kotlin-dsl, shadowjar, fatjar

In tweaking [my buildfile](https://github.com/THUFIR/HelloSeleniumWorld/blob/master/build.gradle.kts), I *seem* [to have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30343603/262852) encountered a [bug](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/336) with `mainClassName`:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloSeleniumWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloSeleniumWorld$ ./gradlew clean ShadowJar --stacktrace
> Task :shadowJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar'.
> No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskValidationException: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.report(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:167)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:150)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:367)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:231)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:133)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:76)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.report(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:67)
        ... 111 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloSeleniumWorld$
```

build file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */


import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    java

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
    application


    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.11"
id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "2.0.4"

}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
 mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

 compile (group= "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name = "selenium-java", version = "3.+" )

    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre")

    // Use TestNG framework, also requires calling test.useTestNG() below
    testImplementation("org.testng:testng:6.14.3")
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application
    mainClassName = "HelloSeleniumWorld.App"
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    // Use TestNG for unit tests
    useTestNG()
}
```

Where should `mainClassName` be declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the root of the file. You want something like:
mainClassName = 'com.your.MainClass'

Comment: if you wants to deploy ktor app on heroku .. please read this medium blog on ktor app deployment https://nameisjayant.medium.com/deploy-ktor-app-with-postgresql-on-heroku-ff35df4b5c55

Answer (score 23):

I got the same issue with Gradle 6.7 and `id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.1.0"`, and figured out in Gradle Kotlin DSL, we should set the `mainClassName` like the following.

```
// Required by the 'shadowJar' task
project.setProperty("mainClassName", "com.your.MainClass")
```

After this, it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Just add it before the plugins block.

Comment: if you add `mainClassName = "com.your.MainClass"` to `gradle.properties` also work.

Answer (score 4):

if you are deploying ktor api on heroku and facing **ShadowJar: No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'** then no worries , simply update the version of shadow plugin to 6.0.0 (updated version)

```
dependencies {          
    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.0.0'
}
```

and error is gone

Comment: I had to update shadow plugin to the 7.1.2 version. The 6.0 has produced the same error

Answer (score 1):

[That suggestion worked for me](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/336#issuecomment-355389693)

> If you define mainClassName before you apply the plugin, the build succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

A newer solution, which is (already) supported in Gradle v6.7.1, and default in v7.#

```
application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    getMainClass().set("org.organisation.HelloWorld")
}
```

Comment: It would be good to note that while this is supported in gradle 6.7.1+. The shadowJar plugin still does not support using this, until shadowJar 7.0.0. AND, shadowJar 7.0.0 requires gradle 7+. So, you may want to clarify this. I still get the error with shadowJar 6.1.0 and gradle 6.9, using this method for setting the `mainClass`

Comment: Yes, it seems like in order to get rid of `mainClassName` deprecation with gradle <7.0, you have to update shadowJar to 7.0, which requires gradle 7.0 :smiling:

In that case no preparatory work can be done, it has to be done in one big branch/MR. @Verhagen, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

If someone getting this problema with micronaut + kotlin + gradlew kotlin, just add this on your build.gradle.kts:

```
application {
    mainClass.set("com.you.package.YourApplication.kt")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kevinmm's comment

In my case, `micronaut` `kotlin` `graphql` with `build.gradle.kts`, I had to upgrade the ShadowJar plugin version to `7.1.2` as well to support the `gradle 7.4` version's `mainclass.set("com.xyz.AbdApplication")` as per the plugin doc

https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow#latest-test-compatibility

Below is the code of my `build.gradle.kts` for any noobs like me out there

```
plugins {
    application
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("kapt")
    groovy
    jacoco
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.abc.xyz.YourClassName")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my `build.gradle.kts` worked for me.

```
application {
    project.setProperty("mainClassName", "com.your.MainClassKt")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple tasks in a single gradle.build file that creates jar with different mainClass names, you can do something like this:

```
shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

task taskJar1(type: ShadowJar, dependsOn: shadowJar){
    zip64 = true
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    archiveBaseName = 'jar-1'

    from sourceSets.main.output
    setMainClassName("com.org.team.MainClass1")

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "com.org.team.MainClass1"
    }

    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } {
        exclude "META-INF/INDEX.LIST"
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    from zipTree(shadowJar.archiveFile)
}

task taskJar2(type: ShadowJar, dependsOn: shadowJar){
    zip64 = true
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    archiveBaseName = 'jar-2'

    from sourceSets.main.output
    setMainClassName("com.org.team.MainClass2")
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```